# Read string from binary file

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, binary

I want to read bytes 1,2 and 3 from a file. I know it corresponds to a string (in this case it's `ELF` of a Linux binary header)

Following examples I could find on the net I came up with this:

```
with open('hello', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(1)
    bytes = f.read(3)
    string = struct.unpack('s', bytes)
    print st
```

Looking at the official documentation of [struct](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html) it seems that passing `s` as argument should allow me to read a string.

I get the error:

```
st = struct.unpack('s', bytes)
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 1
```

EDIT: Using Python 2.7

Comment: Please specify the Python version you are using. In Python 2 "str" and "bytes" are aliases. In Python 3, file.read() tries to convert bytes into unicode using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Grapsus: it is false. `f.read()` returns `bytes` on both Python 2 and 3 if the file is opened in a binary mode `'b'` (OP uses 'rb' i.e., binary). `open` in *text* mode uses `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` encoding that *sometimes* may be utf-8 in Python 3

Comment: don't use `bytes` name. It shadows the builtin function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your special case, it is enough to just check

```
if bytes == 'ELF':
```

to test all three bytes in one step to be the three characters `E`, `L` and `F`.

But also if you want to check the numerical values, you do not need to unpack anything here.  Just use `ord(bytes[i])` (with i in 0, 1, 2) to get the byte values of the three bytes.

Alternatively you can use

```
byte_values = struct.unpack('bbb', bytes)
```

to get a tuple of the three bytes.  You can also unpack that tuple on the fly in case the bytes have nameable semantics like this:

```
width, height, depth = struct.unpack('bbb', bytes)
```

Use `'BBB'` instead of `'bbb'` in case your byte values shall be unsigned.

Comment: Actually, your `bytes` already is the string you are looking for, i. e. you can just test `if bytes == 'ELF': …`.  Sometimes things are just easy ;-)

Comment: why is it a comment: `f.read(3) == b'ELF'` should be at the top of the answer.

Comment: If you need integers instead of bytestrings; you could use `bytearray(bytestring)` or `a = array.array('B'); a.fromfile(file, 3)`. To read structured data from a binary file, you could use [`struct.Struct.unpack_from(buf)` or `file.readinto(ctypes_structure)` or `(ctypes_structure * N).from_buffer(mmap_file)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17246128/4279)

Comment: At the time of the writing of my comment, only an additional question in a comment stated that constant `'ELF'`.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2, `read` returns a string; in the sense "string of bytes". To get a single byte, use `bytes[i]`, it will return another string but with a single byte. If you need the numeric value of a byte, use `ord`: `ord(bytes[i])`. Finally, to get numeric values for all bytes use `map(ord, bytes)`.

```
In [4]: s = "foo"

In [5]: s[0]
Out[5]: 'f'

In [6]: ord(s[0])
Out[6]: 102

In [7]: map(ord, s)
Out[7]: [102, 111, 111]
```

Comment: I am bit confused on the return type of read in python2.7. I opened a file in a binary mode, and read a byte say `byte = f.read(1)`. When I do `print type(byte)` it says `str`. Is "string of bytes" different from normal strings. Which datatype in python maps to "string of bytes"