# Read binary mode in python2.7 returns a 'str' type. Why is it so?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

My objective is to read a text (or) file byte by byte in Python. I came across few stack overflow questions: [Reading binary file and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte/1035456)

and using the following method:

```
with open("./test", "rb") as in_file:
    msg_char = in_file.read(1)
    print(type(msg_char))
```

And am geting the output as

```
<type 'str'>
```

I checked this on one other question [Read string from binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424095/read-string-from-binary-file) which says that *read returns a string; in the sense "string of bytes".* I am confused. Following is the question:

1. Is "string of bytes" different from conventional strings (as used in C/C++ etc..).

Comment: In Python 2 `str` and `bytes` are the same thing. Python 3's `str` will be `unicode` in Python 2.

Comment: `msg_char = ord(in_file.read(1))` now you got 8 bit value. **Be  carefull on encoding**

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2 the differentiation between text and bytes isn't as well-developed as it is in Python 3, which has separate types - `str` for text, in which the individual items are Unicode characters, `bytes` for binary data, where the individual items are 8-bit bytes.

Since Python 2 didn't have the `bytes` type it used strings for both types of data. Although the Unicode type was introduced into Python 2, no attempt was made to change the way files handled data, and decoding was left entirely to the programmer.

Similarly in C, "string" originally meant string of bytes, then wide character types were introduced later as the developers realized text was rather different from bytes data.

As a programmer you should always try to maintain separation between string data and the bytes that are used to represent it in a particular encoding. The simplest rule is "decode on input, encode on output' -- that way you know your text is using appropriate encodings.