# How to pass a C struct to Python to get data?

Tags: python, c, struct, popen

I have code for both Python and C that need to communicate to each other through a pipe created by Popen. I have a test struct in C that needs to be passed back to Python but I can't seem to reconstruct that struct on the Python side. This is a much more complicated project but the struct I created below is just an example to get the code to work, and I can try to figure out the more advanced things later. I am not an expert in C, pointers and piping, and I do not have a clear understanding of it. Most of the C code below is just from my readings.

Python:

```
testStruct = struct.Struct('< i') 
cProg = Popen("./cProg.out", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
data = ""
dataRead = cProg.stdout.read(1)
while dataRead != "\n":
    data += dataRead
    dataRead = cProg.stdout.read(1)

myStruct = testStruct.unpack(data)
print myStruct.i
```

C:

```
typedef struct{
    int i;
} TestStruct;

int main(void)
{
    int wfd = fileno(stdout);
    TestStruct t;
    t.i = 5;
    char sendBack[sizeof(t)];
    memcpy(sendBack, &t, sizeof(t));
    write(wfd, sendBack, sizeof(sendBack));
    write(wfd, "\n", 1);

}
```

But when I run the Python code I get the error:

> unpack requires a string argument of length 4

Like I said I do not understand how structs and C. If there's any suggestion on refining this code, or better yet another suggestion on passing a C struct back to Python to unpack and grab the data. I can read and write through the pipe, the code I have posted are just snippets from my actual code. I know that the issue has to do with sending of the struct back to Python through stdout.

Comment: `print` the length of `data`. What do you get? Also, is this python 2 or 3? String handling changes.

Comment: You're reading 1 byte, but the error message *clearly* indicates that you need to give it 4 bytes.

Comment: related: [reading struct in python from created struct in c](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17244488/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of reading data in Python from a C program through a pipe.

**C Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int i;
    int j;
} TestStruct;

int main() {
    TestStruct ts = {11111, 22222};
    fwrite(&ts, sizeof ts, 1, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

**Python 2.7 Program**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from struct import calcsize, unpack

cprog = Popen("cprog", stdout=PIPE)

fmt = "@ii"
str = cprog.stdout.read(calcsize(fmt))
cprog.stdout.close()

(i, j) = unpack(fmt, str)
print i, j
```

Comment: Don't use [`from xxx import *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I agree. I used it for "simplicity", but probably shouldn't have. I'll change it.

Comment: Thanks @ooga, this is what I needed. I just had to change my format to native (@) and it fixed the problem. Would you happen to know how to pass a char array in the TestStruct of an unknown length back?

Comment: That probably wasn't the problem since your machine is most likely little-endian and therefore `<` should have worked (as it does for me). Don't focus on one little detail; note every difference from your attempt. In particular, note that you used `unpack` incorrectly. Now to read a string of unknown length from the C program, if it ends with a newline (and doesn't contain embedded newlines) you could read it with `cprog.stdout.readline()`.