# Python Struct for Binary Data

Tags: python, file, struct, binary-data

I'm trying to read binary files containing a stream of float and int16 values. Those values are stored alternating.

[float][int16][float][int16]... and so on

now I want to read this data file by a python program using the struct functions.

For reading a block of say one such float-int16-pairs I assume the format string would be "fh".
Following output makes sense, the total size is 6 bytes

```
In [73]: struct.calcsize('fh')
Out[73]: 6
```

Now I'd like to read larger blocks at once to speed up the program...

```
In [74]: struct.calcsize('fhfh')
Out[74]: 14
```

Why is this not returning 12?

Comment: related: [reading struct in python from created struct in c](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17244488/4279)

Comment: Generally, what you would want to do is provide some class that buffers your incoming data, and then hands the bytes to you as needed just like the file read function would.  I suspect that this is not your problem, though; many operating systems *already do this kind of buffering for you.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: that class is called `file` in Python :) e.g., see my answer in the link I've provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the documentation:

> > Note By default, the result of packing a given C struct includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment for the C types involved; similarly, alignment is taken into account when unpacking. This behavior is chosen so that the bytes of a packed struct correspond exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct. To handle platform-independent data formats or omit implicit pad bytes, use standard size and alignment instead of native size and alignment: see [Byte Order, Size, and Alignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct-alignment) for details.
> >
> > https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

If you want `calcsize('fhfh')` to be exactly twice `calcsize('fh')`, then you'll need to specify an alignment character.

Try `'<fhfh'` or `'>fhfh'`, instead.

Comment: Cool, thank you a lot for these very swift responses!

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the byte order or Endianness as size and alignment are based off of that So if you try this:

```
>>> struct.calcsize('fhfh')
>>> 14
>>> struct.calcsize('>fhfh')
>>> 12
```

The reason why is because in `struct` not specifying an endian defaults to `native`

for more details check here: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/struct.html#struct.calcsize