# .dat file in python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv

I'am doing a project in python using OpenCV. I have to store a large amount of integer data(features of images in the database) in a separate file. I can use .txt file but it stores integer values as strings. 
Is there any way that I can store integer values directly as integers in python like .dat file in MATLAB.?

Comment: What do you mean *"integer values directly as integers"*?!

Comment: I mean that if I try to store 5 in .txt file, it will be stored as a character, not integer.

Comment: What's an *"integer"*, though? Are you talking about binary representation? How many bits per number?

Comment: Please show the work you have already done.

Comment: the integers are probably in a `numpy` array. You could use its serialization methods e.g., something like [`numpy.savez_compressed()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed). Otherwise,see [reading struct in python from created struct in c](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17244488/4279) -- the writing is even simpler, just call `file.write(array_with_c_types)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to pack the integers in a bytes format and write them to a dat file.

With integers, this will result in a file that contains 4 bytes per integer, which would save a bit of space (over text format) if you have very large numbers. If you have smaller numbers, a csv format may be better.

```
import struct

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

with open('data.dat', 'wb') as data_file:
    data_file.write(struct.pack('i'*len(data), *data))
```

Then to read it back in

```
with open('data.dat', 'rb') as data_file:
    values = struct.unpack('i'*len(data), data_file.read())
```

Comment: it is probably inefficient for image data with millions of pixels. There are [other options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833610/dat-file-in-python#comment51653849_31833610)

Comment: It probably is. The most efficient and compressed format is probably the image itself.