# Save data as a *.dat file?

Tags: python, database, save

I am writing a program in Python which should import `*.dat` files, subtract a specific value from certain columns and subsequently save the file in `*.dat` format in a different directory.

My current tactic is to load the datafiles in a `numpy` array, perform the calculation and then save it. I am stuck with the saving part. I do not know how to save a file in python in the `*.dat` format. Can anyone help me? Or is there an alternative way without needing to import the `*.dat` file as a `numpy` array? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to save *any* files in Python?  If not - have you tried consulting the Python documentation?  If not, I'd recommend doing that or checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536714/python-save-to-file).

Comment: There is no specific "dat" format.

Comment: Can you specify what dat format are you talking about? It is a binary file? or text file with some specific format? Really there is no standard dat format... you can create your own format if you want to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming your file looks like

```
file = open(filename, "r")
```

all you need to do is open another file with "w" as the second parameter

```
file = open(new_file-path,"w")
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

if your data is not a string, either make it a string, or use

```
file = open(filename, "rb")
file = open(filename, "wb")
```

when reading and writing, since these read and write raw bytes

Comment: If data is produced by numpy, there is an error: "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray"

Comment: Just changed it to include for that

Answer (score 4):

You can read and export a .dat file using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
input_df = pd.read_table('input_file_name.dat')  
...  
output_df = pd.DataFrame({'column_name': column_values})  
output_df.to_csv('output_file_name.dat')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `struct` to pack the integers in a bytes format and write them to a dat file.

```
import struct

data = [# your data]
```

Open:

```
with open('your_data.dat', 'rb') as your_data_file:
    values = struct.unpack('i'*len(data), your_data_file.read())
```

Save data:

```
with open('your_data.dat', 'wb') as your_dat_file:  
    your_dat_file.write(struct.pack('i'*len(data), *data))
```

[Reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31833680/7942600)

Answer (score 0):

The .dat file can be read using the pandas library:

```
df = pd.read_csv('xxxx.dat', sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=1)
```

`skiprows=1` will ignore the first row, which is the header.

`\s+` is the separation (default) of .dat file.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but opening, writing to, and subsequently closing a file should count as "saving" it. You can test this yourself by running your import script and comparing the last modified dates.