# How to transfer a C struct of structs to python using cpython

Tags: python, c, cpython

I want to transfer a struct, containing structs, in C to python, using cpython.

```
//main.c
#include <Python.h>

struct properties {
  struct position
  double velocity;
}

struct position{
  double rx;
  double ry;
  double rz;
}

struct velocity{
  double vx;
  double vy;
  double vz;
}

void main(int argc, char** argv){
Py_Initialize();
struct properties pr;
position po = &pr.position;
velocity v = &pr.velocity;
_Py_fopen("f.py", "r+");
Py_Finalize();
}
```

```
#f.py
#import numpy as np
#pr = properties()
#po = pr.po
#v = pr.v
#poabs = np.abs(po.rx + po.ry + po.rz)
```

How can I manipulate the structs in a python file?

The only way I can think of is to transfer every variable individually,

```
//main.c
...
PyObject* rx = po.rx;
...
```

write getter methods for each variable according to https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html (1.4.)

```
//main.c
static PyObject* emb_getrx(PyObject *self, PyObject *rx)
{
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(rx);
}
```

and embed each getter method

```
//main.c
static PyMethodDef EmbMethods[] = {
    {"rx", emb_getrx, double, "Return rx."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static PyModuleDef EmbModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "emb", NULL, -1, EmbMethods,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
};
```

to then import

```
#f.py
import emb
```

The real code contains many more structures and variables. Is there an easier way?

Comment: related [reading struct in python from created struct in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244488/4279)

Comment: Based on your `main.c` and the link you provided, it looks like you're trying to embed Python in a C application, rather than creating a C extension module for CPython. Is that correct?